# error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of <T> unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to create a unique pointer to a `<Node>` type variable:

```
#include <memory>

struct Node
{
    int val;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next;

    Node(int value, std::unique_ptr<Node> nextNode) : val(value), next(std::move(nextNode)){};
}

int main()
{
    Node headNode = Node(1, nullptr);
    std::unique_ptr<Node> head = std::make_unique<Node>(headNode);

    return 0;
}
```

And when I'm compiling this code I'm getting the following error:

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Node'
    return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...));
                               ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::make_unique<Node, Node &>' requested here
    std::unique_ptr<Node> head = std::make_unique<Node>(headNode);
                                      ^
note: copy constructor of 'Node' is implicitly deleted because field 'next' has a deleted copy constructor
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
                          ^
note: copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'unique_ptr<Node>' has a user-declared move constructor
  unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& __u) _NOEXCEPT
```

Comment: Don't copy an object that is non-copyable.

Comment: Did you mean to make a copy of headNode, or did you just intend to make a unique_ptr to it? Or something else?

Comment: To make a unique pointer to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::make_unique<Node>(headNode);
```

This constructs a unique `Node` by attempting to copy-construct it from another `Node`.

`std::unique_ptr` is not copyable, by definition (that would be due to the "unique" part of "unique_ptr"). This means that any class that contains a `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable by default, and its default copy-constructor is deleted.

This is the reason for your compilation error. You would get the same compilation error without involving `std::unique_ptr`:

```
Node node2{headNode};
```

This results in the same compilation error. You have two options:

1. Implement a copy constructor for `Node` that does whatever would be a meaningful result for copy-constructing your `Node`.
2. Re-engineer your code, in some way, that avoids copy-constructing `Node`s.

If your described goal is "a unique pointer to a  type variable", then this does not require copy-constructing it, merely:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> head = std::make_unique<Node>(1, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Should work

```
#include <memory>

struct Node
{
    using NodePtr = std::unique_ptr<Node>;

    int val;
    NodePtr next;

    Node(int value, NodePtr&& nextNode)
        : val(value)
        , next(std::move(nextNode))
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto headNode = std::make_unique<Node>(1, nullptr);
    auto head = std::make_unique<Node>(0, std::move(headNode));

    return 0;
}
```

At line `std::unique_ptr<Node> head = std::make_unique<Node>(headNode);`
make_unique calls ctor for `Node` and `unique_ptr` (making 1 allocation)

So, args passed into std::make_unique() are used to build `T` instance.
Your `Node` has ctor, that takes 2 params, not 1.

`std::unqiue_ptr` hasn't copy ctor and copy `operator=()` (e.g auto newPtr = oldPtr), so every function that deals with `std::unique_ptr` in argument list, should take this smart pointer by rvalue-reference - `std::unique_ptr<T>&&`. And final call must look like this `f(std::move(ptr))`, where `f` - function, or in our case - ctor of Node

If you are not familiar with `T` - consider `T` as AnyType